# Which distribution created by summing independent random integer variables has the best autocorrelation with its own translates?

Tags: pr.probability

A random walker on the natural numbers can start at any location $x_0$, with $0< x_0  \le S$.

At each time step $t$ they are given instructions to take $k$ steps to the right with probability $p_t(k)$. Here $0 \le k \le K$.

The goal is to find the "most mixing" choice of $p_t(k)$ - the set of (time dependent but not position dependent) walk instructions which erases the most about the initial starting position.

More precisely, let $P(x|x_0=i,T)$ denote the probability distribution after $T$ such iterations for a walker who began at position $x_0=i$.  That is, for given $S,K,T$ we wish to minimize
$$
E=min_{p_t(k)} max_{i,j} D(P(x|x_0=i,T),P(x|x_0=j,T))
$$
where $D$ denotes the total variation distance between the two probability distributions.

If the full problem is not readily solvable, the most interesting things would be (i) Bounds on $E$ for given $S,K,T$ and (ii) For a given $S$, bounds on $K,T$ required to achieve a given $E$.

Comment: I think this question (which I think is interesting) will be easier to understand if the random walker is erased and the question is restated, in accordance with the title, in minimalist terms of sums of iid rv's and their shifts. Also, the term autocorrelation seems inappropriate here.

Comment: A colleague suggests the form:

"Which distribution over nonnegative integers, resulting from a sum of T independent random variables each from 0 to K, has the best correlation with its own translates by up to S to the left or right (as measured by worst-case variation distance)"
If you think its better I will replace it (I'm slightly confused about left and right translation part, the original question is only for "stepping" to the right)